# Pass Property as Expression to child of child

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda, blazor

I have a somewhat Generic Input component, which extracts a couple of things from the property to autogenerate a input. Normally I use it like this:

```cs
<GenericInput For="() => _myDto.MyProperty"></GenericInput>
```

The Generic Input then has the Parameter:

```cs
[Parameter]
public Expression<Func<T?>>? For { get; set; }
```

And does a couple of checks, so everything the Generic Input does is working for sure:

```cs
protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    if (For == default)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Expression body is null");
    }
    if (For.Body is not MemberExpression member)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{For}' refers to a method, not a property.");
    }

    if (member.Member is not PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Expression '{For}' refers to a field, not a property.");
    }
}
```

What I now want to do is pass the property to a Child Component, which then uses the Generic Input, so Something like that:

Parent:

```cs
<ChildComponent For="() => _myDto.MyProperty"></ChildComponent>
```

Child:

```cs
<GenericInput For="@(For)"></GenericInput>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<T?>>? For { get; set; }
}
```

But this is not working as `For.Body is not MemberExpression member` is true, resulting in the `ArgumentExcpetion`.

How can I pass my Property from the parent component via my ChildComponent to the Generic Input?

Comment: Your code works well in my test. How about use `<GenericInput For="@(For)" T="T"></GenericInput>`

Comment: Hmm, I just created a minimum demo example, and it is working for me as well. I am not sure what's different in my app but will find out.